# Terraform aws_s3_object's etag keeps uploading unchanged files on each apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

My `resource "aws_s3_object"` used to work correctly with `etag = filemd5(local.file)`.

At a point, I wanted to rename the bucket and did that by changing the field `bucket` of the `resource "aws_s3_bucket"`. `terraform apply` then destroyed the previous bucket and created the new one as expected, but did not upload the file to the new one. I think this behaviour is also expected because the `etag` didn't change. So I updated the `etag` to also include the bucket name:

```
etag = format("%s%s", local.bucket_name, filemd5(local.file))
```

This update made the uploading of the file happen. However, if I `terraform apply` again (and again) without any changes of the file or the bucket name, the uploading happened again (and again):

```
~ etag = "368491ebe1c33275ef9355fc9600b96f" -> "my-bucket368491ebe1c33275ef9355fc9600b96f"
```

I think the output of `terraform apply` indicates that terraform kept storing only the md5 part of the `etag` in its state file. Why?

Comment: In my question I've mentioned that the `file` wasn't changed. The output md5 in the `terraform apply` was also a proof for the fact.

Answer (score 1):

It is not actually Terraform that stores the MD5 in the ETag, but AWS. See [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html):

> Objects that are plaintext or encrypted by server-side encryption with Amazon S3 managed keys (SSE-S3) have ETags that are an MD5 digest of their data.

So you'll need to change back to just using the MD5.

It is interesting that TF didn't re-upload the files after the bucket was recreated; I would have thought that when it tries to refresh the details of the file resource it would find that it no longer exists, and I would have also thought that a change to the bucket attribute would have been picked up as a change. I'm not sure why neither of those got picked up.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I thought terraform only calculates / stores / compares the md5 locally and didn't speculate the possibility that terraform could retrieve the md5 provided by S3. Assume it is true, that would have already made the uploading happen when the old bucket was destroyed and the new one was created. So, yes, am confused at the point too.